# Elementor ruins page layout

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I use Astra (latest version) and Elementor 3.64, tried to switch off every plugin, clear cache, restore CSS and change CSS setting to external file, nothing helps.

I have some products in my catalog, and those product posts that I have created previously seem to have no problem with CSS.

But when I create a new product, the page has no margins or paddings whatsoever. The most interesting thing is that when I start editing previous product posts, the margins and paddings also disappear there. That's why I try not to change other "healthy" posts with Elementor, because it ruins them.

I tried looking at the CSS code through F12, it shows that CSS codes for ast-separate-container and ast-woocommerce-container simply disappear and I have no clue why that happens. Other pages that I haven't opened with Elementor have these code lines with all margins and paddings. Somebody help?

Normal page: https://atomycatalog.kz/product/atomi-centella-nabor/

Ruined page:
https://atomycatalog.kz/product/atomi-dorozhnyj-nabor-6-dlya-ochishcheniya/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating Elementor to version 3.7.0 before?

I've got news from some friends that there is a bug in version 3.7.0 which makes some layouts messy, they say downgrading still doesn't change anything.

The only way they fix the messy layouts problem is with restore the database if you have any backup for the version on date where you feel everything is still fine.

Elementor developer team will work hard to fix this bugs in the next update. I am sure of it

If this doesn't help you, come back and ask again:)